# Cómo agrupar los datos con las condiciones dadas

Tags: mysql

Tengo una consulta donde genero las ventas que se han realizado, las cuales se deben de agrupar si han sido por pagos de *contado* o *crédito* y si son a crédito debe agruparse en los dias de vencimiento que el cliente ha sugerido para la venta.

**CONSULTA**

```
SELECT tpag.nombre_tipo_pago,
       COUNT(tpag.nombre_tipo_pago) AS contador,
       MONTH(fact.fecha_factura) AS mes_venta,
       fact.dias_vencimiento_factura
FROM factura fact
INNER JOIN tipo_pago tpag
ON tpag.id_tipo_pago = fact.id_modo_pago_factura
WHERE fact.id_empresa_factura = '1'
GROUP BY mes_venta, tpag.nombre_tipo_pago, fact.dias_vencimiento_factura
ORDER BY mes_venta ASC
```

**RESULTADO**

[image: Resultado Query]

**REQUERIMIENTO**

Un requerimiento más me sugiere que debo agrupar los datos entre rangos de 0 a 14, 15 a 30 y de 31 a 45 días.

**RESULTADO ESPERADO**

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|  nombre_tipo_pago   |     contador     |    mes_venta     | dias_vencimiento |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Contado        |         1        |        8         |        0         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Contado        |         3        |        9         |        0         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Crédito        |         1        |        9         |       12         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Crédito        |         3        |        9         |       30         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Contado        |        50        |       10         |        0         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Crédito        |         4        |       10         |       12         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Crédito        |         6        |       10         |       30         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Crédito        |         2        |       10         |       45         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

> **Nota:** Pude haberme equivocado en algún dato, dado que lo hice a ojo.

**PREGUNTA**

¿Cómo agrupar los datos con las condiciones dadas?

Comment: Entiendo la lógica de `contador` pero no entiendo la de `dias_vencimiento`, ¿sería la fecha máxima de cada grupo?

Comment: `dias_vencimiento` son los dias de plazo que le da el usuario a un cliente para ejercer el pago, por eso deseo agrupar los datos en los rangos dados (pero eso aplica más para las ventas a crédito), esto para generar una gráfica y que el usuario pueda evaluar el numero de ventas que se le adeudan.

Comment: Eso lo entiendo, pero en el ejemplo del resultado esperado, muestras una columna para `dias_vencimiento` que está agrupada, entonces cual sería el valor de ese dato? un ejemplo tienes 3 créditos, uno a 0, otro a 10 y otro a 12 días, los tres pertenecen a un solo grupo, serán una sola fila con el valor de contador en 3, pero quieres ver `dias_vencimiento`, el tema es: ¿para que esa columna? o ¿que valor de los 3 créditos mostramos?

Comment: `dias_vencimiento` solo lo tengo como una base para verificar que esté correcta la consulta, realmente es como lo dices en tu ejemplo, donde 3 creditos pertenecen a un solo grupo, dado que estan en 0, 10 y 12 días por lo que caben dentro del rango de 14 días, no es relevante saber los días de vencimiento, solo saber si está en el rango marcado. de  14, 30 o 45 días. Espero haberme hecho entender...

Comment: Perfecto, entonces creo que la respuesta de Mauricio es lo que estás buscando. Saludos.

Comment: Tenías razón, solo falto completar un poco las condiciones pero cumplía con lo que pretendía. Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si es para Mysql, así también como en PostgreSQL utilizaría un CASE/WHEN .

```
CASE 
    WHEN fact.dias_vencimiento_factura >= 0 and fact.dias_vencimiento_factura <= 14 
        THEN 'grupo1' 
    WHEN fact.dias_vencimiento_factura >= 15 and fact.dias_vencimiento_factura <= 30 
        THEN 'grupo2' 
END as alias_when
```

Y en el group by debes reemplazar fact.dias_vencimiento_factura  por alias_when

Espero te sea útil.

Comment: Hola Mauricio, primero bienvenido a la comunidad, sengundo, `grupo1` y `grupo2` sería?

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida.. Grupo 1 y 2 es figurativo .. ahi podrías poner 0 , 12 o 30 .. según te haga falta..

Comment: Vale, pero estoy teniendo un problema: simbolo (token) inesperado. )cerca de 'grupo2'

Comment: Perdón , pero el ELSE no corresponde en este caso.  Edité el código para que lo veas .

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que buscas es armar una agrupación particular por período, debes armar grupos por dichos períodos y luego agrupar por estos

```
SELECT  tpag.nombre_tipo_pago,
        COUNT(tpag.nombre_tipo_pago) AS contador,
        MONTH(fact.fecha_factura) AS mes_venta,
        CASE    WHEN fact.dias_vencimiento_factura BETWEEN 0 AND 14 THEN '0 a 14 días'
                WHEN fact.dias_vencimiento_factura BETWEEN 15 AND 30 THEN '15 a 30 días'
                WHEN fact.dias_vencimiento_factura BETWEEN 31 AND 46 THEN '31 a 46 días'
                ELSE '+46 días'
        END
    FROM factura fact
    INNER JOIN tipo_pago tpag
        ON tpag.id_tipo_pago = fact.id_modo_pago_factura
    WHERE   fact.id_empresa_factura = '1'
    GROUP BY mes_venta, 
        tpag.nombre_tipo_pago, 
            CASE    WHEN fact.dias_vencimiento_factura BETWEEN 0 AND 14 THEN '0 a 14 días'
                    WHEN fact.dias_vencimiento_factura BETWEEN 15 AND 30 THEN '15 a 30 días'
                    WHEN fact.dias_vencimiento_factura BETWEEN 31 AND 46 THEN '31 a 46 días'
                    ELSE '+46 días'
            END 

    ORDER BY mes_venta
```

Como te decía en mis comentarios `dias_vencimiento_factura` tiene que irse del `select` ya que justamente estás agrupando por esta columna. Básicamente es la misma respuesta de @Mauricio Biott, un poco más extendida.

Answer (score 0):

prueba cambiar el orden del `GROUP BY`. Si no te entendí mal, con eso debería bastar para obtener el resultado que deseas.

Quedaría así:

```
SELECT tpag.nombre_tipo_pago,
       COUNT(tpag.nombre_tipo_pago) AS contador,
       MONTH(fact.fecha_factura) AS mes_venta,
       fact.dias_vencimiento_factura
FROM factura fact
INNER JOIN tipo_pago tpag
ON tpag.id_tipo_pago = fact.id_modo_pago_factura
WHERE fact.id_empresa_factura = '1'
GROUP BY tpag.nombre_tipo_pago, mes_venta, fact.dias_vencimiento_factura
ORDER BY mes_venta ASC
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos!

Comment: La consulta realiza lo mismo, no importa el orden.

Comment: Podrías poner el script de creación de las tablas como para poder probar? Sino son respuestas a ciegas.